# Where is it defined that a JAVA HashTable object will be synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, hashtable, synchronized

At first I thought that all the methods of `HashTable` are synchronized. Looked up the java doc, found none of the methods are declared synchronized. Then where exactly a JAVA `HashTable` object is defined as synchronized?

Comment: I am looking at source code and most of the methods are synchronized.  public synchronized V put(K key, V value) {

Answer (score 3):

Most of the methods are synchronized.  If you look into the source files, you can see the synchronize keywords.

Comment: No, the *documentation* defines it; the source is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Hashtable.java) of the `Hashtable`, you can see that each and every method of the class which we use for iteration or add or remove is `synchronized`, hence we can say that `Hashtable` is synchronized

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. But how is the object getting synchronized? Is it because all the methods are synchronized?

Comment: Sure.  An object is certainly synchronized if everything you can do with it is synchronized.

Comment: @ambar Agree with answer of Louis

Answer (score 1):

The last line of the [class description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) states

> As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to implement the Map interface, making it a member of the Java Collections Framework. **Unlike the new collection implementations, Hashtable is synchronized**. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use HashMap in place of Hashtable. If a thread-safe highly-concurrent implementation is desired, then it is recommended to use ConcurrentHashMap in place of Hashtable.

(emphasis added)

Answer (score 1):

Hashtable is one of the original utility collections and all of those were all synchronized. From the Javadoc description before all the methods: "As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class has been retrofitted to implement Map, so that it becomes a part of Java's collection framework. Unlike the new collection implementations, Hashtable is synchronized."

Answer (score 1):

In javadoc: of java.util.Hastable:

> Unlike the new collection  * implementations, {@code Hashtable} is
>   synchronized.

The methods are synchronized!